# How to add multiple images in flutter (firebase)

Tags: firebase, flutter

how I can add multiple images and store them in an array in firebase ?
every container has a + button so the user can add single image per container then I WANT TO STORE them in my firebase
any help would be greatly appreciated ^^

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what you are showing in your image is fbCloudStore which is use to store information in json structure.

To store the images you may use fbStorge.

here's an snippet I use on my project:

```
Future<String?> uploadFile({
    required FilePickerResult file,
    required String fileName,
    required FirebaseReferenceType referenceType,
  }) async {
    try {
      final ref = _getReference(referenceType);
      final extension = path.extension(file.files.first.name);
      final _ref = ref.child(fileName + extension);

      late UploadTask uploadTask;
      if (kIsWeb) {
        uploadTask = _ref.putData(file.files.first.bytes!);
      } else {
        uploadTask = _ref.putFile(File(file.files.single.path!));
      }
      var url;

      await uploadTask.whenComplete(
          () async => url = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
      print(url);
      return url;
    } on FirebaseException catch (_) {
      print(_);
    }
  }
```

Note that I'm returning the URL of fbStorage in order to associate it with fbCloudStorage

```
final url =
    await FirebaseStorageSer.to.uploadFile(
  file: result,
  fileName: STORAGE_USER_PROFILE_PICTURE,
  referenceType: FirebaseReferenceType.user,
);
if (url != null) {
  await FirebaseAuthSer.to
      .updateUserProfile(photoUrl: url);
}
```

FirebaseReferenceType.user is just a simple enum to simplify ref targets.